# How do you return the "period" part of to a time series?

Tags: r, time-series, floating-accuracy

In `R` you can easily return the `cycle` part of a time series object with the `cycle()` function.  eg.

```
> series <- ts(1:50, frequency = 4, start = 2011)
> cycle(series)
     Qtr1 Qtr2 Qtr3 Qtr4
2011    1    2    3    4
2012    1    2    3    4
2013    1    2    3    4
2014    1    2    3    4
2015    1    2    3    4
2016    1    2    3    4
2017    1    2    3    4
2018    1    2    3    4
2019    1    2    3    4
2020    1    2    3    4
2021    1    2    3    4
2022    1    2    3    4
2023    1    2
```

However, I have never been able to figure out a nice clean way to return the "period" part (eg. the year for quarterly data).  In most cases, you can do a simple:

```
> floor(time(series))
     Qtr1 Qtr2 Qtr3 Qtr4
2011 2011 2011 2011 2011
2012 2012 2012 2012 2012
2013 2013 2013 2013 2013
2014 2014 2014 2014 2014
2015 2015 2015 2015 2015
2016 2016 2016 2016 2016
2017 2017 2017 2017 2017
2018 2018 2018 2018 2018
2019 2019 2019 2019 2019
2020 2020 2020 2020 2020
2021 2021 2021 2021 2021
2022 2022 2022 2022 2022
2023 2023 2023
```

To get the year, however, I have found that for some data (usually high frequency data), the [errors in floating point precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal) will cause the first time point of one period to return the value of the previous period (eg. it was being stored as something like 2010.9999999 rather than 2011 so `floor()` returns 2010).  We can artificially introduce the problem into the data doing the following:

```
> seriesprec <- ts(1:50, frequency = 4, start = 2010.999999999999)
> floor(time(seriesprec))
     Qtr1 Qtr2 Qtr3 Qtr4
2011 2010 2011 2011 2011
2012 2011 2012 2012 2012
2013 2012 2013 2013 2013
2014 2013 2014 2014 2014
2015 2014 2015 2015 2015
2016 2015 2016 2016 2016
2017 2016 2017 2017 2017
2018 2017 2018 2018 2018
2019 2018 2019 2019 2019
2020 2019 2020 2020 2020
2021 2020 2021 2021 2021
2022 2021 2022 2022 2022
2023 2022 2023
```

Now we see the floating point accuracy is throwing off the returned value even though:

```
> all.equal(time(seriesprec), time(series))
[1] TRUE
```

The simplest solution I have found that seems to take care of these edge cases is:

```
round(time(series) - (cycle(series) - 1)*deltat(series))
```

but this seems like reasonably complicated code for a very simple task.  Particularly when `cycle()` is a base function, it seems like there should be another base function to return the other half of the time definition.

By the way, I am aware of packages that handle dates and times very nicely, but since a lot of the things I do eventually get wrapped into packages, I would rather not add something like `lubridate` as a dependency for something that can be solved with one (very cumbersome) line of base `R` code.

Thank you!

Comment: `trunc(time(ldeaths))`

Comment: @d.b The object returned by `time()` for a time series object is not of class `timeDate` so the ability of `trunc` to round to specific time precision does not help.  Instead it functions like `floor()` in this context and has the same floating point precision problems as that function.

Comment: Just add a small amount,  `floor(time(series) + eps)`  You can use any reasonably small number as `eps`.  `eps <- deltat(series) / 2` is a general possibility.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck, you can also add small amount using `offset`: `floor(time(seriesprec, offset = 0.5))`

Comment: @d.b your most recent answer seems to be working.  Could you please write up along with an explanation of what `offset` is doing so I can accept it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way may be to add a suitably small value to `time` before taking `floor` or `trunc`. As *G.Grothendieck* mentioned in the comments, `deltat(series)/2` can be a suitable small value. And using `offset` with `time` can be a way of adding that small value. From `?time`

> offset
>
> can be used to indicate when sampling took place in the time
>   unit. 0 (the default) indicates the start of the unit, 0.5 the middle
>   and 1 the end of the interval.

Adding `offset = 0.5` to `time` is equivalent to adding `deltat(series)/2`.

So, you should be able to get the correct *period part* using

```
floor(time(seriesprec, offset = 0.5))
```